# Android Camera Preview filtering

Tags: android, camera, preview

I'm an absolute Android noob, and I want to create an app where I can filter the camera preview in real-time by manipulating the raw YUV420 data. In API level 8, the setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer appeared and my question is:

In API level 7, data supplied to onPreviewFrame couldn't be changed (i.e. changes to data didn't result in any change of the preview, which is as it should be I guess). Is this also true for setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer ??

Edit: I found this article [Image processing with Android Camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373254/image-processing-with-android-camera) which has code for doing pretty much what I want anyway (not bearing in mind my original question...)