# How to Stream a Camera Intent into a bitmap

Tags: java, android

How would I stream my camera data into a bitmap?  I want to stream it into a bitmap and then create a mutable bitmap and do some image processing on it.  I'm having two issues 1) my camera intent brings me to the Android image picker when I'd like to stay in my app and have the camera turn on in the background -- 2) I don't know how to access the camera data in real time to propagate a bitmaps ARGB values on the fly.

I know how to take a picture with a camera intent and use this picture to update a static bitmap - but I'm looking for something a little more dynamic with a constantly updating bitmap.  For reference - I never need to save the image data.  I am must looking for a frame-by-frame update.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would I stream my camera data into a bitmap?

By using a `Camera` directly instead of invoking a third-party app.

> but I'm looking for something a little more dynamic with a constantly updating bitmap

The only way to do this is to process preview frames from a `Camera` object.

Comment: This answer helped me to be able to google to find what I was looking for 'process preview frames from Camera object'.  It lead me to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162376/android-show-processed-camera-preview  which led me to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373254/image-processing-with-android-camera - which led me to these great examples: http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/index.html